# When returning value from flask, using AJAX, it says [Object, Object]

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

So I am trying to make my project update prices live from an API. And I managed to do it, but the prices itself are float values (int's and strings works just fine!). I ran `console.log` & `print()` to see what the issue might be, on `print()`it said `<class 'dict'>` and on the `console.log` I got back `Object`.

I am guessing I have to change something, to receive float values?

Anyways, here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bprices', methods=['GET'])
def bprices():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[can provide another key IF NEEDED]').json()

    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1],
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return jsonify(products=products)
```

And here is my HTML + Script:

```
  <h3>Products</h3>
  <table id="products_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <script src="/static/jquery3.5.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root | tojson | safe }};
        (function () {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/bprices",
            function(data) {
                var products = data.products;
                var table_body = document.createElement("tbody");
                $.each(products, function(index, product){
                    var product_name = product.id.toString();
                    var product_quantity = product.sell_price;
                    var product_price = product.buy_price;
                    var row = table_body.insertRow();
                    var name_cell = row.insertCell();
                    name_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_name));
                    var quantity_cell = row.insertCell();
                    quantity_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_quantity));
                    var price_cell = row.insertCell();
                    price_cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(product_price));
                })
                $("#products_table tbody").remove();
                $("#products_table").append(table_body);
            }
            );
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10000);
        })();
    </script>
```

Thanks !:)

Comment: So is the problem in `product_quantity = product.sell_price` and `product_price = product.by_price`

Comment: yeah, I think that is the problem. Don't know what the issue is though.

Comment: Any chance you could modify your original post , and add what the terminal output is when you do print(products)

Comment: `I ran console.log & print() to see what the issue might be, on print()it said <class 'dict'> and on the console.log I got back Object.`

Comment: not so sure what you mean. @AkibRhast

Comment: In your route function please add this line print(products), and then add the output of that to your original post.

Comment: Doing that will just give me every single product from my request function? If you need it, here: https://pastebin.com/eYzTMx06 @AkibRhast